# Using test systems versus spec systems

Tags: bdd, minitest

I'm extremely new to behaviour-driven development, and I'm trying to wrap my head around something fundamental: the difference between test systems and spec systems.

So far I've been using the Ruby-based minitest/test library where a typical unit test would look something like this:

```
require "minitest/test"

class TestMeme < Minitest::Test
 def test_that_kitty_can_eat
   assert_equal "OHAI!", @meme.i_can_has_cheezburger?
 end
end
```

On the other hand, a spec from minitest/spec would look something like this:

```
require "minitest/autorun"

describe Meme do
 describe "when asked about cheeseburgers" do
   it "must respond positively" do
     @meme.i_can_has_cheezburger?.must_equal "OHAI!"
   end
 end
end
```

So what exactly is the difference between tests and specs? Should I choose, or can I use both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are showing is merely the style of tests. You can either use the minitest API to create tests, or you can use the spec DSL to create the tests. As you point out, they are functionally equivalent. The difference is a matter of preference.

The larger question is TDD vs. BDD. Both advocate for driving the design of your software by writing tests. First you write a test that fails, then you write only the code needed to make it pass, then you refactor your code to make it right while keeping your tests passing. This is called the TDD cycle.

BDD goes a bit farther and specifies how developers can interact with users to define the stories that developers work off of. And it advocates for a different role for mocks than most TDD practitioners use. But those are small differences compared to the very large area that both methodologies agree.

You can practice TDD with spec-style tests, and you can practice BDD with test-style tests. You can mix and match, with spec-style `describe` and `it` blocks with `assert_*` assertions, or test style class and method definitions with `must_*` expectations. The differences between the test-style and spec-style syntax is superficial.

Answer (score 1):

The BDD test is a business-analyst friendly unit test, meanwhile a unit test is just developer-friendly. BDD defines a language to interact between developers and BAs.

Also ideally BA could produce a human oriented but automatically *executable* documentation, well integrated with agile, formatted as User Stories.

I think you just need to read more about [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development), wiki has good article.